# Jquery: "NaN" error related to attribute of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

**I am trying to use JQuery Selector Function, and my codes:**

```
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="RECNUM" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="LOCAL" value="ALE">
<script>
var hiddenvalue = new Array();
var hiddenname = new Array();
$.each($("input:hidden"), function() {
    hiddenname.push($(this).attr("name"));
    hiddenvalue.push($(this).val());
});

for(var hi=0; hi<hiddenname.length; hi++){  
    document.write("<p>hidden:" + +hiddenname[hi]+ "   "+ hiddenvalue[hi] + "</p>");
}
</script>
</body>
```

**While the result is:**

```
hidden:NaN 0

hidden:NaN ALE
```

**Where is my "name" attribute?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that unnecessary `plus`, It will actually try to convert the `string` into `number`, in your case that `string` cannot be converted into a `number` so that it is returning `NAN`

Try,

```
for(var hi=0; hi<hiddenname.length; hi++){  
    document.write("<p>hidden:" + hiddenname[hi] + "   " + hiddenvalue[hi] + "</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code....

```
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="RECNUM" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="LOCAL" value="ALE">
<script>
var hiddenvalue = new Array();
var hiddenname = new Array();
$.each($("input:hidden"), function() {
    hiddenname.push($(this).attr("name"));
    hiddenvalue.push($(this).val());
});

for(var hi=0; hi<hiddenname.length; hi++){  
    document.write("<p>hidden: "+hiddenname[hi]+"   "+hiddenvalue[hi]+"</p>");
}
</script>
</body>
```